# How to get count of affected rows of update statement in adodb

Tags: php, mysql, sql, adodb

Im using adodb and want to have the count of affected rows of an update statement:

```
$sql = "UPDATE newsletter
        SET
        datetime_confirm = NOW(),
        confirmation_code = NULL
        WHERE
        confirmation_code = ?";
    $sqlP = $db->Prepare($sql);
    $prepareVals = array($confirmationCode);
    $result = $db->Execute($sqlP, $prepareVals);
```

In my example there is one entry with the given confirmation_code in the newsletter table. So one row gets updatet. So I need the count '1'.

Edit: Not a dublicate because Im searching for a specific method of the adodb framework which archive this.

Comment: How about `SELECT ROW_COUNT();` **[`ROW_COUNT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count)**

Comment: Is [`affected_rows()`](http://adodb.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=v5:reference:connection:affected_rows) what your after?

Comment: @NigelRen that was exactly what I was searching for. Thank you.